# Trying to get a specific column from Auth::user array

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

In our code users (which we access through `Auth:user`) have tips they create. We are trying to implement a profile page, which would list all of the tips the user has already created.

Using `{{ Auth::user->tip }}` returns the array which contains the whole table row for that particular user. I've tried `{{ Auth::user->tip['title'] }}`

Using the above gives the error '*Undefined index 'title'...*' and it points to the blade I have the code in.

Comment: Dump it and see what it contains.

Comment: Please review the how-to-ask guide: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this could solve the problem:

```
Auth::user->tip->pluck('title')
```

This will result an array and if you try to output it, you'll face an error, so you have to loop through it:

```
@foreach(Auth::user->tip->pluck('title') as $title)
    {{ $title }} 
@endforeach
```

Or as a string:

```
{{ implode( ', ', Auth::user->tip->pluck('title')) }}
```